# Socket communication?

Tags: sockets, scripting, runtime, server-side

What are the preferred platforms to implement [TCP socket communication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_socket)?

I'm interested in:

- scripting languages (eg [Swocket](http://swocket.sourceforge.net/) for Python)
- and runtimes (eg [.NET](http://ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2002/10/21/sockets.htm) / [Java](http://www.j2ee.me/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/BasicJava2/socket.html)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, we use Apache Mina,

http://mina.apache.org/

Its performance rivals C implementation.

Comment: Exactly. Mina is implemented as a scalable NIO server.!

Answer (score 1):

Socket communication implemented using [Java NIO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_I/O) might be a good method. Some of Java based web servers use it. I remember [jetty](http://www.mortbay.org/jetty/) using it. [Here](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/nio/index.html) is a link from Sun.