# Can I run a Python script as a service?

Tags: python, web-services, sockets, webserver

Is it possible to run a Python script as a background service on a webserver? I want to do this for [socket communication.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422929/socket-communication)

Comment: It is possible, for more detailed answer please provide more information: what operating system do you use, do you want to start the service on reboot etc.

Comment: Think "Unix/linux servers", that web hosts typically have.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can make it a daemon.  There is a PEP for a more complete solution, but I have found that this works well.

```
import os, sys

def become_daemon(our_home_dir='.', out_log='/dev/null', err_log='/dev/null', pidfile='/var/tmp/daemon.pid'):
    """ Make the current process a daemon.  """

    try:
        # First fork
        try:
            if os.fork() > 0:
                sys.exit(0)
        except OSError, e:
            sys.stderr.write('fork #1 failed" (%d) %s\n' % (e.errno, e.strerror))
            sys.exit(1)

        os.setsid()
        os.chdir(our_home_dir)
        os.umask(0)

        # Second fork
        try:
            pid = os.fork()
            if pid > 0:
                # You must write the pid file here.  After the exit()
                # the pid variable is gone.
                fpid = open(pidfile, 'wb')
                fpid.write(str(pid))
                fpid.close()
                sys.exit(0)
        except OSError, e:
            sys.stderr.write('fork #2 failed" (%d) %s\n' % (e.errno, e.strerror))
            sys.exit(1)

        si = open('/dev/null', 'r')
        so = open(out_log, 'a+', 0)
        se = open(err_log, 'a+', 0)
        os.dup2(si.fileno(), sys.stdin.fileno())
        os.dup2(so.fileno(), sys.stdout.fileno())
        os.dup2(se.fileno(), sys.stderr.fileno())
    except Exception, e:
        sys.stderr.write(str(e))
```

Comment: In the code snippet above, I can see at least one problem: sniffing daemon presence isn't done before attempting to launch a fresh instance.

Comment: sniffing?  Do you mean checking if the daemon is already running?  if so, this is done in a different procedure before call the above.

Comment: nice demostration, very fun ! There's a lot of method to do that python-daemon, subprocess with custom shell calls (nohup, &), but this is very simple to understand. Nice :)

Comment: in practice, the demonization part may be outside (systemd, supervisord). For a web app, your code is even further removed from the demonization, e.g., all you need is to create a wsgi application without worrying how it is deployed (e.g, [flask deployment](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/deploying/)).

Answer (score 7):

You might want to check out [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/).

Comment: I checked it out, and its quite confusing to grasp. So Twisted is a Python library, which keeps a python script running forever for whatever communication task? (eg. Sockets)

Comment: Twisted is a python library for writing servers.
Once you write a server in twisted, you can use 'twistd -y server.py' to run it as a daemon

Answer (score 2):

on XP and later you can use the **sc.exe** program to use any .exe as service:

```
>sc create
Creates a service entry in the registry and Service Database.
SYNTAX:
sc create [service name] [binPath= ] <option1> <option2>...
CREATE OPTIONS:
NOTE: The option name includes the equal sign.
 type= <own|share|interact|kernel|filesys|rec>
       (default = own)
 start= <boot|system|auto|demand|disabled>
       (default = demand)
 error= <normal|severe|critical|ignore>
       (default = normal)
 binPath= <BinaryPathName>
 group= <LoadOrderGroup>
 tag= <yes|no>
 depend= <Dependencies(separated by / (forward slash))>
 obj= <AccountName|ObjectName>
       (default = LocalSystem)
 DisplayName= <display name>
 password= <password>
```

You can start your pythonscript by starting the python interpreter with your script as argument:

```
python.exe myscript.py
```

Comment: I have a .py Python script. Where's the EXE?

Comment: you just can start python interpreter with your script as argument: python.exe myscript.py

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't just use sc.exe to make any process a service. It must implement the Windows Service interface, such as that provided by the win32serviceutil module (part of pywin32).

Answer (score 2):

There is the very helpful [Pypi package](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon/) which is the basis for my daemons written in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is for Windows, see [this recipe based on srvany](http://agiletesting.blogspot.com/2005/09/running-python-script-as-windows.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about linux, it is as easy as doing something like ./myscript.py &

Comment: What Andre said. I neglected to mention nohup because I usually just run screen and detach, so there's no need for me to do that. These downvoters are vicious.

Comment: But even if you're running screen, you haven't created a true daemon, it's still a child of your screen session. nohup isn't the best solution either, but it's a quick way to run a once off daemon.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_%28computer_software%29 "a daemon is a computer program that runs in the background". I think this qualifies.

Comment: And if you keep reading: "In a Unix environment, the parent process of a daemon is often (but not always) the init process (PID=1). Processes usually become daemons by forking a child process and then having their parent process immediately exit, thus causing init to adopt the child process. This is a somewhat simplified view of the process as other operations are generally performed, such as disassociating the daemon process from any controlling tty. Convenience routines such as daemon(3) exist in some UNIX systems for that purpose" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_%28computer_software%29

Comment: ...  ... starting from screen doesn't give the process over to init, and starting from nohup doesn't create the process as a process group leader. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_%28computer_software%29#Types_of_daemons

Comment: I'm not saying `nohup ... &` doesn't work, I'm just saying that we should tell people how to make daemons that have the correct parent process, have the correct umask, are in the correct working directory, won't inadvertently grab a controlling tty, and have their output correctly redirected.