# Set up basic Twisted Reactor

Tags: python, twisted, reactor

I am very new to using Twisted. I have set up a protocol in a .py and it works perfectly. The thing is that currently to test it I have to ssh into my server and run it. I would like to have it running as a service/server so it is always serving my protocol. I read on the twisted site something about .tac files but I'm not sure how to tie that in with the protocol file I've written.

All I have is a simple socket based iPhone app that sends messages to the reactor and receives messages back.

I would like this to start up when the server boots. Much like an apache server works.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your question vaguely implies that you're trying to have your server application always running.  However, it's unclear why you can't just run your server application when your server host boots up to achieve this.  Please clarify.

Comment: check if this answers your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1603109/how-to-make-a-python-script-run-like-a-service-or-daemon-in-linux

Comment: @llazzaro That is similar but not quite the same I need the script to be constantly running in the background like a web server not a timed wait between running. Deamonizing it is what I want and I know there is a way that twisted does this internaly. I am hoping someone knows how to do just that.

Comment: @cwieland check that someones answered how to daemonize a python script. http://www.jejik.com/articles/2007/02/a_simple_unix_linux_daemon_in_python/ he copy his answer from there. if you find a twisted way that will be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Daemonization in twisted is achieved via the `twistd` shell command. I found this tutorial quite useful: [Using the Twisted Application Framework](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/application.html)

Comment: Great! that was exactly what I was looking for. Will this start it on a reboot, or do I need to restart it?

Comment: I think you will have to create a startup script for that.