# Automate script run time in python

Tags: python-2.7

How can I write a script which should run at every 3 hours?

I do not want to use crontab.

Comment: You can look for "while loop" and "time.sleep".

Answer (score 0):

You need deamon exemplified in [How to make Python script run as service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16420092/how-to-make-python-script-run-as-service)
and make changes

```
import time 
class MyDaemon(Daemon):
    def run(self):

        while True:
            time.sleep(60 * 60 * 3)  # Delay for 1 hour in seconds
            print "3 hours pass."
```