# Python daemon killed after init.d

Tags: python, linux, daemon, init.d

I have a python script daemonized using the code in this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16420140/3399564).

I created the init.d script at `/etc/init.d/MakeDCP` with content

```
#!/bin/bash
python /opt/some/path/to/file/MakeDCPLinux.py start
```

Then ran `update-rc.d MakeDCP defaults`

Until here everything is fine. However, after restart the PID file is created and the code goes to the loop but the code is not running when I log in.

The command works from the terminal.

The Linux server is a VM with no GUI.

Comment: Logging in your script should tell you whether it starts at all and where it fails.

Comment: My code looks the database for pending records else sleep for 1 min. The code enter the while(stop file not exist) but never writes an error or that it exited the code. the line that I am sure it closes on is `time.sleep(60)`

Comment: Check your app for : used a external file(permission,path), additional port, which service required(update-rc.d defaults not a solution, give some time sleep for `all required service is alive` or use service_checker code)

Comment: @dsgdfg can you explain more ? note that the python logger didn't log any exceptions.

Comment: Because your app not start, nearest top line : sql_connection, file_connection. `try: connect_to_sql; except Exception,e: logger.log(str(e))`. did you have similar code in your app ?

Comment: I have all code in `try: ... except BaseException as e: logging.exception(e)`