# Wrapping python+keras+tensorflow 'as a service' to receive prediction requests from PHP?

Tags: linux, python-2.7, tensorflow, keras

I run a python script in order to load keras, tensorflow and the keras model. 
Then I can start making predictions, but this takes a few seconds to load everything.

I can loop inside the python script and get good performance predicting in batches, but I want to have also good performance with via independent prediction requests from PHP.

Anyone had success approaching like this? [How to make Python script run as service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16420092/how-to-make-python-script-run-as-service)

Comment: What do you mean 'permanently loaded'? What are you using this for? In a Python script, you can simply use `model = load_model('name_of_model.h5')` and then use `model.predict(x, batch_size=32, verbose=0)` to make predictions. The documentation for model.predict() is [here](https://keras.io/models/model/#predict)

Comment: You only have to load the model once and you can predict however many times you want in the python script

Comment: can you provide some sample script and a bit more explanation? Do you load your model every iteration? Do you have python permanently running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a very good solution. Converting my prediction python script into a FLASK app and running the flask app with a Python WSGI HTTP Server called Gunicorn! and it works like a charm!

Comment: I am trying to replicate something similar. Do you mind sharing your code?

Answer (score 0):

I've found this resource with many options to resolve this problem and to make available the trained model for a production environment https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/545qei/question_about_using_pythonkeras_in_production/