# Configure a Python as a service in AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

How do I configure a Python script to run as a service (re-launch on system restart, restart on failure) in Amazon AWS EC2 instance?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can create a `systemd` service on the ec2 instance to achieve this. Steps are:

1. Create a service definition file:

   ```
   sudo vi /lib/systemd/system/mypythonservice.service
   ```
2. Add the systemd unit file definition. You can check [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-systemd-units-and-unit-files) or the systemd reference guide for more details:

   ```
   [Unit]
   Description=My Python Service
   After=multi-user.target

   [Service]
   Type=idle
   ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /home/myuser/mypythonproject.py
   Restart=on-failure

   [Install]
   WantedBy=multi-user.target
   ```
3. Set the necessary permissions on the file:

   ```
   sudo chmod 644 /lib/systemd/system/mypythonservice.service
   ```
4. Reload the systemd daemon:

   ```
   sudo systemctl daemon-reload
   ```
5. Enable the service to start on reboot:

   ```
   sudo systemctl enable mypythonservice.service
   ```

And of course you can add all of this as part of a EC2 Instance User Data script to automatically configure on instance launch.

Comment: We use sysvinit and not systemd. Any suggestion for that?

Comment: You can have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16420092/how-to-make-python-script-run-as-service or this: https://gist.github.com/int64ago/01fe54e45ffc28442c20

Answer (score 1):

[image: aws and python logo]

Configure a Python as a service in AWS EC2

After much unsuccessful research to set up a Python API written on custom port 8080 to run on Amazon's Linux AMI operating system (AWS), I decided to solve this dilemma and share the solution with all of you.

See the solution in [this link](https://gist.github.com/phpenterprise/101679894fc15c51c628c299df56a64a).

Comment: this really helped me alot