# AWS CodeDeploy failing in AfterInstall due to ScriptTimedOut

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

I have connected AWS to github

**appspec.yml**

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: /
    destination: /home/mybot
hooks:
  AfterInstall:
    - location: RunMyBot.sh
      timeout: 300
      runas: root
```

**RunMyBot.sh**

```
#!bin/bash

cd /home/mybot/
yum install -y python3-pip python3 python3-setuptools
sudo python3 -m pip install --user --upgrade pip
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
python botMain.py
```

Error:

[image]

I want to run my main file - botMain.py, but it doesn't run.

I tried removing the install lines from script coz it said they were already installed, but still I was getting a timeout and my botMain.py was not running.

Comment: What does `botMain.py` do? Is it like a server, just running and waiting for connections?

Comment: @Marcin yes, its the only file which contains python code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably it should be `python3`, not `python`. But anyway, your deployment hangs because if `botMain.py` is a server, it just starts and does not finish. Due to this, CD timeouts waiting for `botMain.py` to complete its execution which never happens.

To properly run your `botMain.py` you should run it a **daemon** service. For that you can create custom unit file for `systemd` on linux. One example of that is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51915848/configure-a-python-as-a-service-in-aws-ec2).

Comment: So, do I need to create another script for BeforeInstall? I added the code from the link you gave with my own paths to RunMyBot.sh. But, I am getting the same error - ScriptTimedOut. Also warnings: [stderr]Vim: Warning: Output is not to a terminal
[stderr]Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal

Comment: @DeadPool You can't run your code the way you do because it will hang. You have to create a systemd service as I explained. Have you tried that?

Comment: yes I did. I have added the systemd lines in my RunMybot.sh. And I tried using another way before for which I had added ApplicationStop but later removed it. During deployment it is now trying to find the file that I used for ApplicationStop which doesn't exist. I found some solutions on net, but none of them are working. It gives me the error- 'Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted' when I try to restart code-deploy. It can't find code deploy. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67193222/sudo-service-command-not-found)