# Systemd Daemon in Python with watchdog support

Tags: python, systemd, watchdog

I want to write a daemon in python which gets started via systemd.

I want to use [Type=notify](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd#Service_types), this way I don't have to do the double fork magic.

According to the docs:

> The reference implementation for this notification is provided by libsystemd-daemon.so

... how to do this with Python?

Comment: Possibly related: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/python-systemd/daemon.html http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13069634/python-daemon-and-systemd-service

Comment: @Robᵩ The question you mention does not solve my question, since my question is about a daemon with **watchdog** support. If my daemon hangs in an endless loop, I want systemd to know that the service does not respond. Without watchdog systemd things my service is alive as long as the process runs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Probably, you could use [sdnotify](https://github.com/bb4242/sdnotify) python module which is a pure-python implementation of [sd_notify](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/sd_notify.html) protocol. Actually, the protocol is rather simple, so the module implementation is quite short.

To use watchdog machinery you should add `WatchdocSec=<smth>` to the unit file, and then send `WATCHDOG=1` messages on a regular basis from your service. Check `Restart=` option as well.

Comment: Nice, the package can be installed via pip. Thank you.

Comment: It's how I've discovered it a while ago :). `pip search` facility is rather handy.

Answer (score 1):

use the package
 `https://pypi.org/project/systemd-python/`
it is the offical systemd devs and maintained.

Comment: You didn't answer the question.  Give an example of how to notify systemd from python using that package.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`systemd-python` package](https://pypi.org/project/systemd-python). Specifically, consider the `notify` function in the `daemon` module.

```
from systemd.daemon import notify
notify("WATCHDOG=1")
```

According to the [docs](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/python-systemd/daemon.html#systemd.daemon.notify) this will...

> Send a message to the init system about a status change.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented the functionality in [systemd-watchdog-thread](https://pypi.org/project/systemd-watchdog-thread/)