# How do we run below celery commands in production server?

Tags: python, django, redis, celery

```
celery -A app worker -Q priority_high -B -l debug --purge -n priority_high_worker

celery -A app worker -Q default -B -l debug --purge -n default_worker

celery -A app beat -l info
```

As of now we are running the three commands in screens. What is the more production way of running these commands?

Comment: Depends on your OS.

Comment: I'm using linux.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to create daemons is with [supervisord](/questions/tagged/supervisord). [sentry](/questions/tagged/sentry), which also uses django and celery [recommends using supervisord](https://docs.sentry.io/server/installation/python/#running-sentry-as-a-service) to run the workers - you can adjust the configuration to suit your set up:

```
[program:celery-priority-high]
directory=/www/my_app/
command=/path/to/celery -A app worker -Q priority_high -B -l debug --purge -n priority_high_worker
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=syslog
stderr_logfile=syslog
```

You can, of course, also run django itself using this method.

---

If supervisord is too much bloat for your needs, you can also create init scripts for your init system of choice (eg. [systemd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13069634/python-daemon-and-systemd-service)).

Comment: IMO systemd eliminates most of the need for supervisord since it replicates much of it's functionality

Comment: That's why I listed it as an option. I don't use systemd myself.