# How to toggle process state via command line?

Tags: python, python-3.x

We are trying to create a simple command line utility that tracks some  metrics over an unknown period of time (start/stop triggered via command line externally).

For example,

```
python metrics-tool.py --start-collect

... run some additional commands external to metrics-tool ...

python metrics-tool.py --stop-collect
```

Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions on how an application can receive a command for a "second time"? Is this even possible, or a good way to do this?

It almost sounds like this should be a service, configurable at runtime by an endpoint?

Comment: Usually a bad idea. Just make it run synchronously in the console, CTRL+C to break, and use bash features to run in the background or to run as a daemon, to redirect logs etc. If you're still going that way (you shouldn't), `--start-collect` should daemonize your process, writing a pid file. `--stop-collect` should read the pid file and act accordingly on the daemon process.

Comment: Can you add a socket to `metrics-tool` and have it listen for start/stop *commands*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does sound more like a service which can be started and stopped, via Systemd (or Supervisor) for example.

Using Systemd means there's no need to daemonise your Python process yourself: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30189540/736221

You can of course do that if you want to, if you're using something other than Systemd: https://pagure.io/python-daemon