# Proper way to write a daemon in 2019 in Python

Tags: python, linux, daemon, systemd

**TL;DR;**

I would like to write a daemon in Python, but I feel that PEP 3143 is overkill now that almost everybody uses `systemd`. I am looking for advice for a good start to write a daemon in Python.

**Context**

By reading other related questions on SO, it seems there is a before and an after `systemd`. The articles I have read are more than 10 years old and I feel that nowadays it is much simpler to achieve what I want to do.

I would like to write a program container that can be run either:

- In the front (blocking) (`$ ./foo`)
- In the background (`$ ./foo &`)
- In a detached state (`$ ./foo start`, `$ ./foo stop`).
- Managed by `systemd` (`$ sudo systemctl start foo`)

Being able to `start` and `stop` the program by itself would require these commands:

```
$ daemon start
$ daemon stop
$ daemon status
```

Also if the program is able to demonize itself it would also take care of some side effects (prevent zombies, double fork, pidfile, logging...)

I have yet not figured out how to manage the log. Since a daemon is detached from a TTY, it should redirect `stdin`, `stdout`, `stderr` to `/dev/null` and use a logger instead. To use a logger I can see different options:

1. Use Syslog, but require a write access to `/dev/log`
2. Use `daemon.log` through `stdout` and `systemd`, but requires `systemd`
3. Use a custom log file that will be specified with `--log=~/foo.log`
4. Use `stdout`/`stderr` because the process is not detached

For the PID file, the traditional location is in `/var/run/` in which most users have no access. So the user should be able to configure the `--pidfile`.

From this I realize that building a simple daemon is not an easy task and I do not know from where to start.

One trivial approach would be to have two separated programs. One simple blocking program that performs the task, use `stdout` and one process manager that can do what `systemd` do, but at a user level.

If I would summarize my question in one sentence I would say:

> Is it worth it to use `PEP3143 Standard daemon process library` in 2019 to write a daemon in Python instead of relying on a daemon manager such as `systemd`?

Comment: systemd is more advanced than some py lib.

Comment: as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13069634/python-daemon-and-systemd-service/30189540#30189540)

Comment: but expect occasional core dumping…