# Python not querying database in loop

Tags: python

I currently have a process running that should call a method every 10 seconds. I see that it actually calls the method at that interval, but it seems to not execute something in the code. Weird thing is, is that when I cancel the loop, and start it new it does actually do it the first time. Then when I keep it running it does not do anything.

```
def main():
    try:
        while True:
            read()
            time.sleep(10)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
```

Above is the loop, and the code here is actually the beginning of the method that is being called, and I found out that it does not actually get results in the `results`, while the file has changed. In this case it gets data from a .json file

```
def read():
    message = Query()
    results = DB.search(message.pushed == False)
```

Am I overlooking something?

Comment: How are you sure that `read()` is being called after `KeyboardInterrupt` ? Ideally your program will exit upon `KeyboardInterrupt`(Ctrl+C). Try to put a print statement in `read()` and check if you see that statement on console. If you wan to run this continuously, you have to run it as a [daemon process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1603109/how-to-make-a-python-script-run-like-a-service-or-daemon-in-linux).

Comment: I had indeed put a print statement there, so I know it's being called. The file is being run as a service on the server, it keeps calling the method every 10 seconds. It seems to run fine, it's just that it does not get any results from the database

Answer (score 1):

Solved. I had the DB declared globally and that did not go so well. It is being fixed by declaring it just before the statement.