# How to force a Python script run in background on Linux

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, background

Is it possible? For example the script understands if it was executed not in background and it closes and reopens in background with `nohup python3 script.py &`? Can I do that with `sys.argv`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible.You can register it be a service.This site maybe be helpful:[How to make a Python script run like a service or daemon in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1603109/how-to-make-a-python-script-run-like-a-service-or-daemon-in-linux)

Comment: thanks. what's the difference between a service and a daemon?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/192058/what-is-technical-difference-between-daemon-service-and-process