# How to run python daemon process on Linux boot

Tags: python, centos7, daemon, boot

I have the following simple python script `test.py` (toy example)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import time
from time import gmtime, strftime
from daemon import runner

import config
import subprocess


class App():
def __init__(self):
    self.stdin_path = '/dev/null'
    self.stdout_path = '/dev/tty'
    self.stderr_path = '/dev/tty'
    self.pidfile_path =  '/tmp/foo.pid'
    self.pidfile_timeout = 5
def run(self):
    while True:
        file = open('/var/www/myfile.dat'+strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime()), 'w+')
        file.write("Hello World")
        file.close()            

        time.sleep(20)

app = App()
daemon_runner = runner.DaemonRunner(app)
daemon_runner.do_action()
```

I want to run that script on the boot of Linux Centos 7. 
For that reason I have added the line in `rc.local` file

```
  touch python /root/scripts/test.py start
```

but unfortunately the script doesn't run.

P.S. When I run that script from command line `python test.py start` it works perfectly.

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1603109/how-to-make-a-python-script-run-like-a-service-or-daemon-in-linux

Comment: I know how to create deamon process in python (script above) the problem is that I can't run it on boot

Answer (score 0):

Create a cron job. Check this [link](https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/automate-system-tasks-using-cron-on-centos-7/) on how to set up cron jobs on CentOS. Then you can call the python script with
`@reboot sleep 60 && /usr/bin/python /path/to/script.py >> /path/to/log/file.log`