# Possible to keep the GCloud VM Instances running without connection?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine, vmware

The title explains the question itself. My problem is every time I connect my VM machine through SSH it always timeouts after a period of time. So I'd like to let my Python script work on itself for like hours or days. Any advice? Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at https://www.tecmint.com/keep-remote-ssh-sessions-running-after-disconnection/amp/

Comment: See @ferregina-pelona for recommended user-level solutions. However, the correct solution is to run your program as a Linux service. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1603109/how-to-make-a-python-script-run-like-a-service-or-daemon-in-linux Which solution to choose? That requires more information than your question provides on what you need to do and what your program does.

Comment: Thank u both. setsid solved the issue @FerreginaPelona !

Answer (score 1):

VM **Instance** will keep running even if your SSH times out.
You can keep the SSH session alive by adding following lines:

```
Host remotehost
    HostName remotehost.com
    ServerAliveInterval 240
```

to `$HOME/.ssh/config` file.

There's a similar option in [PuTTy](https://documentation.help/PuTTY/config-keepalive.html).

---

To keep **process** alive after disconnecting, you have multiple options, including those already suggested in commnets:

- [nohup](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/unohup.htm)
- [screen](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-use-linux-screen/)
- [setsid](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setsid.2.html)
- [cron](https://opensource.com/article/17/11/how-use-cron-linux)
- [service/daemon](https://www.shubhamdipt.com/blog/how-to-create-a-systemd-service-in-linux/)

Decision which one to choose depends on specifics of the task that is being performed by the script.