# SOCKET PYTHON serve code dont working with SSH closed

Tags: python, sockets, ssh

I have a socket serv (a gateway) in python to recive packges from a car tracker. When I put the code to run (python3 filename.py &) in the AWS machine (using a CMD on windows) and I keep  with the SSH open, the code run perfectaly, but the code print some prints on my SSH (until I know, with the "&" in the end off the comand nothing should be print in my SSH).
The problem is: when i close the SSH and open again/other, I do a "ps -axf python3" and the process keep running (ok, that it should be happen) but the code dont "work" more.

This is a part of my code

```
class ThreadedServer(object):     

    
def __init__(self, host, port):
    self.host = host     
    self.port = port     
    self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)     
    self.sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)  
    self.sock.bind((self.host, self.port))  

    
def listen(self):
    global connecteds
    connecteds = {}   
    compareTimeConnecteds()   
    self.sock.listen()

    while True:
        client, address = self.sock.accept() 
        client.settimeout(60*5)               
        threading.Thread(target = self.listenToClient,args = (client,address)).start()       

    
def listenToClient(self, client, address):
    bufferSize = 4096 
    while True: 
      .
      .
      .
      code to process the package from the car tracker
      .
      .
      .

if __name__ == "__main__":
  ThreadedServer('',port).listen()
```

As I said, after if I close the SSH, the code keep running, but it don't enter in the While(TRUE) on the listenToClient, and with the SSH open (start the code and never close) it enter....

I dont know why this happen, I think what the problem is maybe not in the code....

Someone have a ideia why this happen, I am a new in the programming world

2022/07/15 - i needed do a tmux new on my shh to so send execute my python file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think running python programs as daemons using & works as intended.
[How to make a Python script run like a service or daemon in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1603109/how-to-make-a-python-script-run-like-a-service-or-daemon-in-linux)

Instead, once you ssh, try opening a tmux window to start the socket server.

```bash
tmux new
python3 filename.py
```

This will have the running of that program attached to the tmux window now created. To leave the window press "ctrl+b d".

Now you should be able to leave the tunnel and the program will persist.

To go back to the tmux session, run

```bash
tmux a
```

this can also be done with other tools
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/521200/exit-shell-with-running-process-in-foreground

Comment: the best way to do it is gone over in the first link by creating a service and registering it with systemd/systemctl