# Python telegram bot suddenly becomes silent

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I have a telegram bot on python-telegram-bot v20 library. Sometimes it stops answering and I get this error:

```
vThe above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/leakyspoon/Documents/TelegramBots/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/telegram/ext/_application.py", line 1729, in process_error
    await callback(update, context)
  File "/Users/leakyspoon/Documents/TelegramBots/GPT.py", line 301, in error_handler
    await context.bot.send_message(chat_id=492065050, text=message)
  File "/Users/leakyspoon/Documents/TelegramBots/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/telegram/ext/_extbot.py", line 2644, in send_message
    return await super().send_message(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/leakyspoon/Documents/TelegramBots/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/telegram/_bot.py", line 388, in decorator
    result = await func(self, *args, **kwargs)  # skipcq: PYL-E1102
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/leakyspoon/Documents/TelegramBots/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/telegram/_bot.py", line 814, in send_message
    return await self._send_message(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/leakyspoon/Documents/TelegramBots/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/telegram/ext/_extbot.py", line 514, in _send_message
    result = await super()._send_message(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/leakyspoon/Documents/TelegramBots/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/telegram/_bot.py", line 566, in _send_message
    result = await self._post(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/leakyspoon/Documents/TelegramBots/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/telegram/_bot.py", line 476, in _post
    return await self._do_post(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/leakyspoon/Documents/TelegramBots/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/telegram/ext/_extbot.py", line 332, in _do_post
    return await super()._do_post(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/leakyspoon/Documents/TelegramBots/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/telegram/_bot.py", line 504, in _do_post
    return await request.post(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/leakyspoon/Documents/TelegramBots/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/telegram/request/_baserequest.py", line 168, in post
    result = await self._request_wrapper(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/leakyspoon/Documents/TelegramBots/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/telegram/request/_baserequest.py", line 288, in _request_wrapper
    raise exc
  File "/Users/leakyspoon/Documents/TelegramBots/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/telegram/request/_baserequest.py", line 278, in _request_wrapper
    code, payload = await self.do_request(
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/leakyspoon/Documents/TelegramBots/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/telegram/request/_httpxrequest.py", line 240, in do_request
    raise NetworkError(f"httpx.{err.__class__.__name__}: {err}") from err
telegram.error.NetworkError: httpx.ConnectError: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

How can I prevent this error or at least handle it with error handler?

Comment: Please have a look at [this ptb wiki page](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Handling-network-errors)

Answer (score 0):

The reason: as soon as you close your computer, your code stops running.

To prevent that, you can run your program (here: telegram chatbot) on a server, or when using an online integrated development environment and web hosting service, such as https://www.pythonanywhere.com/ (I am more than concerned there are many other alternatives).

Also, to avoid all these lengthy error messages, just catch that with `try ... except`.

P.S.: there are some valid and useful ideas here: [How to make a Python script run like a service or daemon in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1603109/how-to-make-a-python-script-run-like-a-service-or-daemon-in-linux)