# Installing and Starting a CherryPy server script as Windows service (using sc.exe)

Tags: python, windows-services, mod-wsgi, wsgi, cherrypy

I am trying to install and start a simple *CherryPy* server as a Windows service.

Here is the script: (Removed some lines to cut it short. It's fully working when executing manually from the command-line)

```
app = AdminMediaHandler(django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler())
logged_app = TransLogger(app)
server = wsgiserver.CherryPyWSGIServer( ('127.0.0.1', 8632), logged_app, server_name='localhost', numthreads=20 )

try:
    server.start()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    server.stop()
```

I'm using `sc.exe` to install and start the service. Installation goes fine, but I can't seem to start the service.

The command used is: (note there're spaces in the paths, though I'm handeling this with double-quotes, and the `binPath` is working when executing its string manually through the command-line)

```
> sc.exe create "ServiceName" binPath= "\"C:\Path to Python\python.exe\" \"C:\Path to CherryPy Script\cherryserver.py\""

> sc.exe start "ServiceName"
```

I keep getting this error, no matter if attempting to start the service using `sc.exe` or through `services.msc` GUI:

```
[SC] StartService FAILED 1053:

The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.
```

From what I understand, this is happenning because `python.exe` doesn't implement the Windows Service API.

I do not wish to create an `.exe` from the script, using *py2exe*.

I have found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423345/can-i-run-a-python-script-as-a-service/1423369#1423369) that suggests to install the service using different tools than `sc.exe`, called `srvany.exe` & `instsrv.exe`. However, I can't find them in the [Win2K Resource Kit website](http://www.google.co.il/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=win2k%20resource%20kit).

Does anybody know how to install & start this `.py` as a Windows succesfully?

Does anybody know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually used *ServiceInstaller* aka *SMaster*, as [stated in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32404/can-i-run-a-python-script-as-a-service-in-windows-how/597750#597750). The URL in the given answer is broken, and I couldn't find a working URL. I just had `srunner.exe` available locally beforehand.

Note there was another obstacle to overcome though, as *ServiceInstaller* **can't handle files with *spaces* in their paths**.

So, I used the old DOS path formatting for service registration.

Instead of registering `C:\Program Files\MyApp\python.exe`, I registered `C:\PROGRA~1\MyApp\python.exe`.

Answer (score 5):

CherryPy ships with [a module for starting as a Windows service](http://www.cherrypy.org/browser/trunk/py2/cherrypy/process/win32.py). See [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32404/can-i-run-a-python-script-as-a-service-in-windows-how) for instructions on how to install and run it. You'll probably want to switch from your current approach (of passing the Django app directly to the WSGIServer) and use [cherrypy.tree.graft](http://docs.cherrypy.org/dev/refman/_cptree.html?highlight=graft#cherrypy._cptree.Tree.graft) instead.

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for the fastest way for this, without having to make any changes myself.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer [nssm](http://www.nssm.cc/) for installing normal scripts as a service.
You can copy  the *nssm.exe* in the *C:\Windows\system32* or *C:\Windows\SysWOW64* directory depending on your system. After that you are able to install a Service as follow:

```
nssm install yourservicename
```

For a python script you must set the application path to your *python.exe* and the argument is your script self.

[image: Basic configuration for nssm]

Other common commands for start/stop/edit your service are:

```
nssm start yourservicename
nssm stop yourservicename
nssm edit yourservicename
```