# Running a python script persistently

Tags: python, linux, bash, service

I have a script on my machine that I want to start running as the machine boots and will attempt run again should it crash or otherwise fail.

Would this mean turing it into a service?  I realise I could use the crontab and use @reboot, but that doesn't fix the issue should the script crash

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423345/can-i-run-a-python-script-as-a-service

Answer (score 1):

I would start it using init and monitor at interval with a seperate script using crontab watching for a PID file it creates.

Alternatively, if you can find the PID ID using your crontab script (using ps) and re-init the script if it doesn't exist.

My 2 Cents..

Comment: Have you got an example I could take a look at so I can better work out how to do it?